# Corrupted portable SSD, wrong size detected, what to do?

Tags: data-recovery, usb-drive, ssd

I have a 240 GB portable SSD from Transcend.

- [ESD230C Portable SSD](https://us.transcend-info.com/support/product/portable-ssd/esd230c)
- Model: `TS240GESD230C`
- SN: F43849-0038

Recently there have been long delays in reading data.
During another such long delay, I unsafely disconnected the device.
After that, a file about 2 GB in size disappeared from my disk.
I tried to find the missing file through **Filesystem Utils** in **TestDisk**, but the file was missing.

Then I tried to use **Foremost**:

```
Foremost version 1.5.7 by Jesse Kornblum, Kris Kendall, and Nick Mikus
Audit File

Foremost started at Wed Jan  3 20:38:43 2024
Invocation: foremost -w -i /dev/sdc1 -o /home/user/output
Output directory: /home/user/output
Configuration file: /etc/foremost.conf
------------------------------------------------------------------
File: /dev/sdc1
Start: Wed Jan  3 20:38:43 2024
Length: 223 GB (240022786048 bytes)
 
Num  Name (bs=512)         Size  File Offset     Comment
```

After a few more reconnections, the disk stopped connecting correctly altogether.
It is not mounted.
And to make matters worse, its size is now shown as 1023 MB.
I also tried connecting the drive to another laptop and it also shows a size of about 1 GB.

```
$ lsblk -o name,label,size,fstype,model

sdc           1023,8M
```

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 1023,75 MiB, 1073479680 bytes, 2096640 sectors
Disk model:                 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
```

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc -T permissive
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.2.0-39-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SM2258AB-10-00M01000
Serial Number:    (03)5526888-20080228
Firmware Version: 20141211
User Capacity:    1 073 479 680 bytes [1,07 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
Local Time is:    Thu Jan  4 11:02:26 2024 +06
SMART support is: Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability.

SMART Disabled. Use option -s with argument 'on' to enable it.
(override with '-T permissive' option)
```

I found [another case](https://www.elektroda.com/rtvforum/topic3479429.html) when the `SM2258AB` model produces a size of 1023MB.
But I still don’t understand what it can do for me.

After connecting the drive:

```
$ sudo dmesg

[ 1872.464166] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
[ 1872.607596] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2174, idProduct=2000, bcdDevice=80.00
[ 1872.607610] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[ 1872.607616] usb 1-1.3: Product: StoreJet Transcend
[ 1872.607621] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Transcend
[ 1872.607625] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: (03)5526888-20080228
[ 1872.610291] scsi host5: uas
[ 1872.611776] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     StoreJet                  0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1872.616885] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 1872.617558] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] 2096640 512-byte logical blocks: (1.07 GB/1024 MiB)
[ 1872.618040] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 1872.618048] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 1872.618802] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1872.619017] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
[ 1872.619024] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
[ 1872.623443] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[ 1903.644223] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#29 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[ 1903.644237] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#29 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 1f fd f0 00 00 08 00
[ 1903.672418] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 1903.752171] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
[ 1903.903013] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[ 1934.364272] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#3 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: IN 
[ 1934.364288] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#3 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 02 08 00 01 f8 00
[ 1934.388284] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[ 1934.468205] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
[ 1934.615346] scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
```

```
$ sudo journalctl  --follow

Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2174, idProduct=2000, bcdDevice=80.00
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: usb 1-1.3: Product: StoreJet Transcend
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Transcend
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: (03)5526888-20080228
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: scsi host5: uas
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     StoreJet                  0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook mtp-probe[7783]: checking bus 1, device 17: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook mtp-probe[7783]: bus: 1, device: 17 was not an MTP device
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] 2096640 512-byte logical blocks: (1.07 GB/1024 MiB)
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook systemd-udevd[7782]: 1-1.3:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook systemd-udevd[7782]: 1-1.3:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook mtp-probe[7795]: checking bus 1, device 17: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook mtp-probe[7795]: bus: 1, device: 17 was not an MTP device
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook systemd-udevd[7782]: 1-1.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 189:16' failed with exit code 1.
Jan 04 10:34:27 user-notebook systemd-udevd[7782]: 1-1.3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper bind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3 189:16' failed with exit code 1.
Jan 04 10:34:58 user-notebook kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#20 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Jan 04 10:34:58 user-notebook kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#20 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 1f fd f0 00 00 08 00
Jan 04 10:34:58 user-notebook kernel: scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
Jan 04 10:34:58 user-notebook kernel: usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
Jan 04 10:34:59 user-notebook kernel: scsi host5: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
```

What else can I try to do with it?

Assumptions:

**Maybe I can switch some modes? Maybe there is some safe mode with a minimum of capabilities, but which will allow me to read the disk? For example, try working in USB 1/2/3 mode? Or try some other drivers?**

**If the disk is lying about its size, is it possible to somehow indicate the real size to the system and still try to read the data. For example, specify that the disk size is 200 GB and force it to read information from the disk byte by byte until it is read?**

Unfortunately, I have little information about the former structure of the disk.
But I still have a log from launching **Ventoy**, maybe I can somehow restore the partitions.

```
sudo ./Ventoy2Disk.sh -I -s -g -L Data /dev/sdc

**********************************************
      Ventoy: 1.0.64  x86_64
      longpanda admin@ventoy.net
      https://www.ventoy.net
**********************************************

Disk : /dev/sdc
Model: StoreJet  (scsi)
Size : 223 GB
Style: GPT


Attention:
You will install Ventoy to /dev/sdc.
All the data on the disk /dev/sdc will be lost!!!

Continue? (y/n) y

All the data on the disk /dev/sdc will be lost!!!
Double-check. Continue? (y/n) y

Create partitions on /dev/sdc by parted in GPT style ...
Done
Wait for partitions ...
partition exist OK
create efi fat fs /dev/sdc2 ...
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
success
Wait for partitions ...
/dev/sdc1 exist OK
/dev/sdc2 exist OK
partition exist OK
Format partition 1 /dev/sdc1 ...
mkexfatfs 1.3.0
Creating... done.
Flushing... done.
File system created successfully.
mkexfatfs success
writing data to disk ...
sync data ...
esp partition processing ...

Install Ventoy to /dev/sdc successfully finished.
```

Comment: maybe try disable uas for this device? see https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html (IGNORE_UAS usb-storage quirk) but if you're unlucky there's just an issue with the device in general. don't know this model, don't know if a firmware update would change anything.